# Одностраничное ajax приложение

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, spa

Сейчас начал писать такое и понял, что очень много кода уходит на дублирование: приходится писать код для случая, когда на страницу перешли напрямую и когда кусок страницы подгрузился по ajax. И я вот думаю, *а может, ну его*? Может, лучше при первом заходе на любую страницу сайта сначала грузить оболочку, а потом уже основную часть подгружать? Из **плюсов** такого подхода - увеличение скорости разработки (не буду множить одинаковый код) и уменьшение ошибок (в одном месте написал, в другом забыл). **Минус** - первый раз страница будет грузиться в два этапа.  
Какой путь выбрать?

Comment: SPA, грузить аяксом. Добавить server-side, если что, всегда успеете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам уже написали в комментарии, выберите какой-то один подход и следуйте ему.
Если вы пишете именно SPA, то грузите всё ajax'ом. Излишнее количество запросов при первом обращении - одно из известных слабых мест SPA (посмотрите, сколько запросов делает gmail, - и ужаснитесь). :)